# User credentials not recognised in virtual terminal

Tags: command-line, login, authentication

Whenever i switch to a virtual terminal, using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> etc.. it asks me for my user credentials:

`*computername* login:`

At this point i enter my Username, followed by my Password. However the terminal never lets me login and keeps telling me, that i have got the wrong credentials.

---

**EDIT**:
Curiously if i boot up without starting `x`, i can log in via the command line ok, its just virtual terminals that cause problems.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Does your username or password contain non-ASCII or otherwise unusual characters?

Comment: nope, just standard a-z

Answer (score 2):

Normally /var/log/auth* has(have) some clues regarding failure.  Please check there for starters.

Comment: the message im getting in the log file is `no such user`. my username is definitely correct. Do i need to use username+host?

Comment: Are you certain that there isn't locale skew, e.g., your username was input incorrectly?  Also, check what getent passwd $yourusername returns.

Comment: it returns my username, my full name, the location of my home folder and the location of `bin/bash`, ive added more details to the question to clarify

Comment: Hi guys, please troubleshoot by editing your question and answer so information doesn't get buried in the comments. Thanks!